# Как найти путь к каждому ключу во вложенном словаре?

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, словари, nested-sets

Именно к каждому, а не только к последнему. Есть решение, но хотелось бы увидеть элегантный вариант.

Тестовый словарь:

```
test = {'a': {'b': {'c': {},'d': {'e': {}}}}}
```

Должный вывод:

```
[('a',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'd', 'e')]
```

Моё решение:

Сначала найдём путь к конечному ключу каждого вложенного словаря:

```
def recurse(inp_dict, path=()):
    if inp_dict:
        for key in inp_dict:
            for rv in recurse(inp_dict[key], path + (key,)):
                yield rv
    else:
        yield path


after_recurse = recurse(test)
list(after_recurse)

[Out]: [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd', 'e')]
```

Далее сокращаем каждый полученный кортеж на один последний элемент в цикле, добавляем к существующим кортежам и уникализируем список:

```
result = set([x[:y + 1] for x in after_recurse for y in range(len(x))])
sorted(result)

[Out]: [('a',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'd', 'e')]
```

Comment: имеет ли смысл добавить к этому вопросу метку [tag:инспекция-кода]?

Comment: @mymedia метка [tag:code-review] требует наличия рабочего кода. Код в вопросе не выдаёт ожидаемый вывод без дополнительной обработки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы поддерживать произвольные типы, а не только словари в качестве значений, можно тестировать наличие `items` атрибута:

```
def paths(some_dict, path=()):
    for key, value in some_dict.items():
        key_path = path + (key,)
        yield key_path
        if hasattr(value, 'items'):
            yield from paths(value, key_path)
```

Пример:

```
d = {'a': {'b': {'c': {},'d': {'e': {}}}}}
print(*paths(d), sep='\n')
```

[Результат](http://ideone.com/TPYCZb):

```
('a',)
('a', 'b')
('a', 'b', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'd', 'e')
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Словари неупорядочены в Питоне (до Python 3.7, до СPython 3.6), поэтому порядок вывода может меняться в зависимости от окружения, версии Питона и даже от запуска к запуску.

Несколько жертвуя читаемостью и DRY, можно слегка сократить код:

```
def paths(some_dict, path=()):
    for key, value in getattr(some_dict, 'items', lambda: ())():
        yield path + (key,)
        yield from paths(value, path + (key,))
```

[Результат](http://ideone.com/A1JDdy) тот же.

Answer (score 3):

Еще один альтернативный ответ:

```
def foo(root, result, path=()):
    for k, v in root.items():
        new_path = path + (k,)
        result.append(new_path)

        foo(v, result, new_path)


test = {'a': {'b': {'c': {}, 'd': {'e': {}}}}}
result = []
foo(test, result)
print(result)
```

Консоль:

```
[('a',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'd', 'e')]
```

Answer (score 1):

С помощью рекурсии:

```
from copy import deepcopy

result = []

def theway(fork, part):
    if fork:
        for key in fork.keys():
            way = deepcopy(part)
            way.extend(key)
            global result
            result.append(tuple(way))
            theway(fork[key], way)


test = {'a': {'b': {'c': {},'d': {'e': {}}}}}

theway(test, [])

print(sorted(result))
>>> [('a',), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'd', 'e')]
```

Comment: Если `result` передавать в функцию, можно без глобальной переменной обойтись